# symfony 4 doctrine createQueryBuilder with andWhere

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, where-clause

I need help with Symfony 4 and Doctrine (Repository) for beginner.

In my method findChildrenValidAndNotExpired i am trying to get children articles of category.
This give me all related articles to category, but addWhere is not filtering anything. Not valid and out of date articles are showing.

```
public function findAllValidAndNotExpired($max_results = false) {

        $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->innerJoin('c.articles', 'a')
            ->addSelect('a')
            ->andWhere('a.valid = :valid')
            ->andWhere('a.date_expired_from IS NULL OR a.date_expired_from < :now')
            ->andWhere('a.date_expired_to IS NULL OR a.date_expired_to > :now')
            ->setParameter('valid', '1')
            ->setParameter('now', $now)
        ;

        $query = $qb->getQuery();

        return $query->execute();
}
```

Comment: try `return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();`

Comment: Your query has also unnecessary parameters as valid is always 1 and :now could be replaced by CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() or CURRENT_DATE() in case you dont want to compare the time but only the date.